# Macro for saving emails from outlook - Sender name query

Tags: vba, email, outlook

So, the organisation I work for requires *all* project or task related emails to be saved, as part of a formal process, in a specific name format:

YYMMDD-HHmm-SenderName-RecipientName-Subject.msg

We're not allowed to use .pst files for some reason so as you can imagine, doing this individually is tedious in the extreme, and I am lazy, so I decided to try and automate this with a helpful macro. Some intensive googling led me to create the following with help from a website called slipstick:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim objItem As Object
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String
  Dim strFolderpath As String


    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
strFolderpath = "DESKTOP LOCATION HERE"

   For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
   If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
    Set oMail = objItem

  sName = oMail.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

  dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnn", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

  sPath = strFolderpath & "\"
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

  End If
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

This quite happily saves selected emails in a folder on my desktop (for moving on elsewhere) in the format

YYYYMMDD-HHmm-Subject.msg

Try as I might, however, I can't seem to get the sender's name to go in there as well. I've tried using

```
Dim sSenderName As String
```

and

```
Dim sSenderEmailAddress As String
```

With the appropiate additions in the part of the macro which creates the file name:

```
sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnn", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" *& EXTRA BIT HERE* & "-" & sName & ".msg
```

But all this seems to do is add an extra hyphen into my eventual filename.

Note I'm not bothered about adding recipient into the filename, anything with more than a few recipeints would send it sailing past the character limit.

So, what am I doing wrong? I'm a complete newcomer to VBA and have quite enjoyed this little project, so I'd love to know where I'm fouling up. In my defence I'm a mechanical engineer, and I'm pretty sure that hitting my macro with a hammer won't help.

I'm considering trying to write something which will produce a little popup letting me fill in the pertinent info before saving the email, but that's probably a little way beyond me right now. Gotta walk before I can run.

All tips and comments gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Dim sSenderEmailAddress As String` without ever setting it to anything that will be why you just get the double hyphen - it's empty.

Try including:

```
Dim sSenderEmailAddress As String
sSenderEmailAddress = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
```

before you create the file name like this:

```
sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnn", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sSenderEmailAddress & "-" & sName & ".msg
```

You should also be able to use SenderName in this manner if you like, although you're probably best to still run it through your function to strip out certain characters.

Comment: Amazing, worked like a dream. I see what I was doing wrong now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sender name showing in number format "20191220-1012--RE_ PF Admin Charges"

Comment: Exactly where i need to add this line? " sSenderEmailAddress = oMail.SenderEmailAddress"